# Can't align css element to be below another

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a box display under one I currently have but for some reason it's not displaying below it.
[image]

As you can see the second box overlaps the big one, I need the little box to be under the box on the left.

Here is my CSS:

```
.boxResources {
     background-color: #d0e4fe;
     display: inline;
     float: left;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 1px;
     border-bottom-width: 5px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     width: 20%;
     padding-bottom: 16px;
 }

.boxTroops {
    background-color: #d0e4fe;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}
```

boxResources is the box on the left, and boxTroops is the little box that's overlapping.
Thanks for your help guys

I am displaying it with HTML like:

```
<div class = 'boxResources'></div>
<div class = 'boxTroops'></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f73XF/

Comment: Also add the relevant HTML-code, please.

Comment: @MartyMcVry added, although there's not much.

Comment: can you please add a jafiddle example?

Comment: @ebramtharwat Sure, give me a sec and I'll add it.

Comment: ```clear: both``` the .boxTroops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add:

```
.boxTroops {
    clear: left;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f73XF/4/)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realise something to simple would've fixed it, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/f73XF/11/

```
.box {
  background-color: #d0e4fe;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  padding-top: 16px;

}

.boxResources {
    background-color: #d0e4fe;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
 }

.boxTroops {
  background-color: #d0e4fe;
  display: block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
 padding-bottom: 16px;
} 
.col-left{
  float:left;
  width:23%;
}
```